# HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions attribute: missing assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6

i should use [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]attribute in .net 4.6 framework like this:

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
public void HandleExc () { }
```

but I encounter this error "Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference" in visual studio 2015.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Add using statement or use full name: `[System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]`

Comment: It doesn't work. " [..] doesn't exists in namespace "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices" "

Comment: What is your .NET version? This attribute is available only since .NET 4.0